# CMD open new winodw when run php command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe, php

I am trying to execute some PHP command in my cmd window but when i run command it open new window everytime. I need that command run in same window instead of new window.

[image]

Someone can please help me how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to `cd` into `bin` then execute?

Comment: @Anaksunaman yes i have tried it but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

run as admin first command prompt and the php command should run in this window

Comment: I have open cmd as admin but still same problem.